# Count duplicate key values pairs in nested dictionary and remove if that count is >= 10 in python

Tags: python

I currently have a dictionary of dictionaries in Python. They may look something like this:

```
stocks = {
    "VPER": {
        "mentions": 6,
        "score": 120,
        "currentPrice": 0.0393,
    },
    "APPL": {
        "mentions": 16,
        "score": 120,
        "currentPrice": 0.0393,
    },
    "NIO": {
        "mentions": 36,
        "score": 120,
        "currentPrice": 0.0393,
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is look through the nested dictionaries and count how many times `mentions` value is a duplicate, then if that count is 10 remove the nested dictionary (APPL, NIO and so on).

If I had `NIO, APPL, TSLA, EPR, EKG, LPD, TTL, AGR, JKR, POP` as nested dictionaries and they each had their `mentions` key set to a value of `5` then I would want to remove them all from the `stocks` dictionary. Similarly if I had all of those as nested dictionaries and their mentions count was 7, they would be removed.

So, rather than specifying the value of mentions, I am simply trying to count how many times mentions is the same value in a nested dictionary and if that count is 10 or more, delete that entire nested dictionary from `stocks`.

In a previous question I was shown how to find nested dictionaries that contained a specific mention count and then remove them like this:

```
counter = sum(value["mentions"] == 5 for key, value in stocks.items())
if counter > 10:
    stocks = {key: value for key, value in stocks.items() if value["mentions"] != 5}
```

However, I need to not have to specify the mentions value.

Comment: So to rephrase, you want remove all items that share the same `mentions` value if and only if the count of those items are greater than `n`? What if there are multiple duplicated values (e.g. 5,5,5,7,7)? Are they counted as 3 and 2 each or 5 as whole?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`collections.Counter`**[Python-Docs]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```
from collections import Counter

# count the occurrences of mentions values
counter = Counter(value["mentions"] for _, value in stocks.items())

# filter the stocks based on the condition
stocks = {
    key: value for key, value in stocks.items() if counter[value["mentions"]] < 10
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For counting things quickly, I would use the collections.Counter module.

```
from collections import Counter

mentions   = Counter(d['mentions'] for tick,d in stocks.items())
size,count = mentions.most_common()[0]
if count>10:
    for tick,d in stocks.items():
        d.pop('mentions')
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the following steps to solve your problem.

1. Create a class to serialize your json blob (Should end up being a List of stocks).
2. Create a function to filter out all object that meets your `mentions` property

Google will set you free on how to do number 1 and 2 :).